# A bizarre format of html tag

Tags: html, css, href

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ByQw.png)I don't understand this line in an html page :

What does this number mean "636288865835122093" ?

Best regards,

Omar.

Comment: Can you please specify what you are asking for ? give as a link ?

Comment: can you show us more code?

Comment: what your are asking about..?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That is a way to get around the browser's cache.
Many browsers keep a cached copy of the css file locally, even if the css file itself has changed on the server. To prevent this, you can use this trick; put a different number behind it to fool the browser into thinking it's a different file and loading it anyway.
Think of it as a versioning system.